# How to reset xen hyperviser clock

Tags: linux, debian, debian-squeeze, xen

I have a low cost server running Debian Squeeze stable, using the Xen hyperviser. After a very long uptime the clocks of the unprivileged domains will deviate. Restarting the domains will not fix the clocks. I have tried using hwclock to reset the clock, but new domains will still have a clock that is a few minutes off.

I want new domains to have an accurate clock without resetting the whole server. Is there a way to fix the clocks without needing to run ntpd/ntpclient in the unprivileged domains?

Running Xen 4.0.1 provided by Debian Sqeeze
Domain 0 Kernel is Linux 3.2.0 from Debian backports

Answer (score 0):

Use xen.independent_wallclock=1 on dom0. Other workarounds can be found at http://wiki.debian.org/Xen/Clocksource

Comment: error: "xen.independent_wallclock" is an unknown key. Also that site talks about "jiffies" as a clock source, but I only see xen and tsc.

Comment: Sysctl variable xen.independent_wallclock is available only in dom0 domain, so you need to login to your carrier server (dom0) and apply it.

Comment: That unknown key error was from dom0.